# Compiling error with gcc: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'double *'

Tags: c

This is my first program in C, please be gentle guys.

I am trying to get user's input for conversion between temperatures, and use the switch-case to calculate the converted temperatures. My following program throws errors like this when trying to compile it with gcc on Mac:

```
convertTemp.c:17:20: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
      scanf ("%d", &Celcius);
              ~~   ^~~~~~~~
              %lf
convertTemp.c:21:72: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
      printf ("The converted temperature of %d in Fahreight is: %d\n", Celcius, Fahr);
                                            ~~                         ^~~~~~~
                                            %f
convertTemp.c:21:81: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
      printf ("The converted temperature of %d in Fahreight is: %d\n", Celcius, Fahr);
                                                                ~~              ^~~~
                                                                %f
convertTemp.c:25:20: warning: format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'double *' [-Wformat]
      scanf ("%d", &Fahr);
              ~~   ^~~~~
              %lf
convertTemp.c:29:70: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
      printf ("The converted temperature of %d in Celcius is: %d\n", Fahr, Celcius);     
                                            ~~                       ^~~~
                                            %f
convertTemp.c:29:76: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
      printf ("The converted temperature of %d in Celcius is: %d\n", Fahr, Celcius);     
                                                              ~~           ^~~~~~~
                                                              %f
6 warnings generated.
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int choice;
  double Celcius, Fahr;

  printf ("Do you want to convert from C to F (1) or from F to C(2))?");

  scanf ("%i", &choice);


  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
      printf ("Please type the temp in Celcius");
      scanf ("%d", &Celcius);

      Fahr = (Celcius * 9) / 5;
      Fahr += 32;
      printf ("The converted temperature of %d in Fahreight is: %d\n", Celcius, Fahr);

    case 2:
      printf ("Please type the temp in Fahrenheit");
      scanf ("%d", &Fahr);

      Celcius = (Fahr - 32) * 5;
      Celcius /= 9;
      printf ("The converted temperature of %d in Celcius is: %d\n", Fahr, Celcius);

  }

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'm not getting the error about the wrong return type on `main` when I compile this on Linux. Are you sure you're compiling the right file?

Comment: The code you show is different from the code that the compiler saw.  It saw `double main (void)`.  Please post the code and compilation errors that match exactly.

Comment: updated the error message. sorry

Comment: @TonyGW; Read the answer.

Comment: Please note that Celsius has two s's rather than two c's.  It is also a good idea to be consistent in spelling Fahr(enh)eit.

Comment: *"format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'double'"* - What exactly do you not understand in this error message? And the compiler even gives suggestions how to fix it!

Comment: Like @MartinR said...Especially since the error message includes the correction in each case; the `%lf` or `%f` in the 4th line of the error message is the correct spelling of the conversion specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program invokes **undefined behavior**. Using a wrong conversion specifier invokes UB. To scan a `double` use the `%lf` specifier (your compiler warning is already suggesting that).

```
scanf ("%lf", &Celcius);
```

Sample [run](http://ideone.com/zgzR2k).

Comment: Where is my winter cap? :'((((

Comment: @JonathanLeffler; Oh! It comes yearly, right? (I did't tried all).

Comment: Yes.  Search for ['Winterbash'](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=winterbash) on Meta.

Answer (score 3):

For printing doubles and floats, you may use the `%g` and `%f` specifiers. You should also handle the default situation in switch in case of invalid user input. Maybe by printing a helpful error message to the user.

It is also recommended that you `break;` after each switch statement, to prevent execution of further case statements unless that behavior is preferred.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the missing `break;` statements.  Note that the `scanf()` format for `double` is `%lf` but the classic `printf()` format is `%f` (though `printf()` in C99 and C11 recognize `%lf` as a synonym for `%f`, in large part for consistency with `scanf()`).