# Why do I get clang errors when trying to display integers memory locations?

Tags: c, integer

I've looked through questions matching my issue and couldn't find an answer. After creating a program to display the memory locations of integers 'i' and 'k', it didn't compile using clang. When using SoloLearn's IDE it worked fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int k);

int main() {
    int i = 0;

    printf("The address of i is %x\n", &i);
    test(i);
    printf("The address of i is %x\n", &i);
    test(i);

    return 0;
}

void test(int k) {
    printf("The address of k is %x\n", &k);
}
```

These are the errors i'm getting.

```
memory.c:8:37: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("The address of i is %x\n", &i);
                                    ~~     ^~
memory.c:10:37: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("The address of i is %x\n", &i);
                                    ~~     ^~
memory.c:17:37: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
        printf("The address of k is %x\n", &k);
                                    ~~     ^~
3 warnings generated.
```

Do I need to sign the int and if so what should I do?

Comment: Did you carefully read the [documentation of `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) ? It explains the *why* and gives a better way to print pointers (with `%p`). Please read the documentation of every standard function you are using!

Comment: BTW, your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is *not* your compiler. It is running a compiler, probably some version of [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I know an IDE is not a compiler. I understood that they could be using any compiler. So I tried compiling with gcc and had the same issues.

Comment: The warning is very clear and reading the documentation will provide a clear solution. It's a good practice for a beginner to find out yourself. (and yes, that **is** helpful - just think about it).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiling error with gcc: warning: format specifies type 'int \*' but the argument has type 'double \*'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20914858/608639)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print address of a variable or memory location you should use `%p` format specifier. for e.g

```
int i = 0;
printf("The address of i is %p\n", (void*)&i);/* %p format specifier expects argument of void* */
```

From the `C` Standard:

> (C11, 7.21.6.1p8 Formatted input/output functions) "p The argument
>   shall be a pointer to void."

Comment: Thanks. It compiles fine now. But its not the hexadecimal output which is what I want. `%x` just doesn't seem to work. I've searched and searched online for an answer and everyone says just use `%p`. Why doesn't `%x` work?

Comment: Note that `%p` is the format specifier for printing the address & by default it prints in hexadecimal format. For e.g In my system this `int i =10; printf("%p\n",(void*)&i);` prints `0xbfa286cc(some random address)` which is memory location of variable `i`.  Next, `%x` format specifier is for printing hexadecimal equivalent of a `signed integer`, not for printing address. For e.g `int i =255; printf("0x%x\n",i);` prints `0xff` which hexadecimal equivalent of `255`. I hope it clears your doubt.

Comment: Welcome @PaulDaniels on SO !!! if it helps then accept my answer.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: you might want to read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer